# Prevent opening an URL in a webview when the internet connection is lost

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm newbie in android programming, I created Webview app for my website, so far no problem until internet connection is lost, can I prevent to open URL page when I click some link from `Webview` without show "webpage not available"?

My Expected result is:

**Show Toast "No Internet Connection"** and **Still in Same Page** when I click link in `Webview`

i try to use in **onReceivedError**:

```
if (wv.canGoBack()) {wv.goBack();}
```

but still, show "Webpage not available" and back to previous page

**PS:** *This code show Toast "No Internet Connection", but still show "Webpage not available"*

MyCode

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView wv;
    String URL;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(!isNetworkAvailable()){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Internet Connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            URL = "Https://resiongkir.dzakiyyah.com";
            wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
            wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
                    findViewById(R.id.imageView1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    findViewById(R.id.web).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,String description, final String failingUrl) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet Connection Or " + description , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
                }
            });
            wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            wv.loadUrl(URL);
        }
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(wv.canGoBack()){
            wv.goBack();
        }else{
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Anda yakin akan menutup ResiOngkir?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ya", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            MainActivity.this.finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Tidak", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.dzakiyyah.abu.resiongkir.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="228dp"
        android:layout_height="216dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_logo"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.975"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/muava" />


    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/web"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What you want to show instead? Because the toast will disappear but something has to be show?

Comment: if i click link, only show Toast without show webpage not available

Comment: That API only defines one way to intercept page loading - by letting webClient to substute response with its own in `shouldInterceptRequest`. I doubt this will really work for you though.

Comment: Try my answer below! This will load a custom html! You can declare your string html to load! The user has to see something! But if your really want to  make them see nothing load an empty string then! @AbuAyyub

Comment: thanks @Xenolion but, i want to still in same page or current page

Comment: Okay I am editing my answer check it in 1 minute! @AbuAyyub

Comment: I have edited my answer check it @AbuAyyub

Comment: is possible to disable link if no internet connection? So, user cannot move to "webpage not available"

Comment: You maybe could save last successful response in a variable and return it from `shouldInterceptRequest` if page load fails. But this sounds *real* fragile.

Answer (score 3):

You should provide an alternative html to load then. If it is simple just a `String` is required! Like this:

```
@Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,String description, final String failingUrl) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet Connection Or " + description , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        String error_summary = "<html><body> Dear User, An error happened <b>No internet</b> connection!.</body></html>";
        view.loadData(error_summary, "text/html", null);
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
}
```

But if you want the webPage to have the same Url (not loading anything new), The best is to make it `INVISIBLE` this is what you want according to your comments Instead of loading anything just make a webview invisible leading to a blank page!

Instead of loading anything in `onReceivedError` do this:

```
view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

When the Internet Connection remember to make it `VISIBLE` again:

```
wv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```